# PHP Match values for particular keys in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have one multidimensional array and each subarray has same keys with mostly different values. And I need to know if every *id* subkey in this array has identical value. Just return true or false.

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'id' = 123,
        'key1' = 'abcd',
        ...),
    1 => array(
        'id' = 123,
        'key1' = 'efgh',
        ...),
    2 => array(
        'id' = 123,
        'key1' = 'ijkl',
        ...)
)
```

In case above return true.
Thanks and SFE (sorry for english).

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_diff_key.asp || array_diff_key() could help you.

Comment: I've tried foreach loop but it was not as elegant as @Sundar solution. array_diff_key compares two arrays, but I have only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use this function to achieve this
Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

```
<?php
//get the same column values
$sameColumns = array_column($array, 'id');
//find the unique values
$sameColumns = array_unique($sameColumns);
//check the count
if(count($sameColumns) == 1){
    return true;
}
//return status
return false;
```